# what does error type object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

this is my code:

```py
r = int

for q in range(0 + (casovaJednotka - celkovaCasovaJednotka), casovaJednotka + 1):
    r[q] = q + 1
    q = q + 1

for i in range(casovaJednotka, 0, -1):
    for w in range(0 + (casovaJednotka - celkovaCasovaJednotka), casovaJednotka):
        if r[w] != i:
            print(q[w])
        if casovaJednotka - 1 == w:
            print("0\n")
```

and this is the problem:

```py
if r[w] != i:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

and also it has the same problem with

```py
r[q] = q + 1
```

Comment: `r` is not array, so you can't use `r[q]`. That's the meaning of the error you reported.

Comment: `r = int` is setting r to the type `int`

Comment: What do you think `r = int` does?

Comment: so how do I use indexes with r as int?

Comment: @ChristoferKiňo I have modified the indentation to make it valid python as your error didn't seem to be syntax related. Feel free to revert if it no longer matches your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are initializing the `r` variable as an `int` object.
By looking at your code, I can assume that you want `r` to be an array of integers. So instead of defining `r=int`, you can do this.

```py
r=[]
```

OR

```py
r = list(range(10)) #initialize a list of size 10 items
```

To know more about what is TyprError and Python throw this error ([Python Error "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable](https://www.techgeekbuzz.com/blog/python-error-typeerror-type-object-is-not-subscriptable-solution/)), you can read this article, here, I have elaborate on this error in detail.

Comment: if I inicialise
     r = []
I still have porblem with q

Comment: for r=[], you need to use r.append(q + 1)
but for r= list(range(10)) you can use r[q]=q + 1

Comment: now I have problem with q in this: 
        for i in range(casovaJednotka, 0, -1):
            for w in range(0 + (casovaJednotka - celkovaCasovaJednotka), casovaJednotka):
                if r[w] != i:
                    print(q[w])
                if casovaJednotka - 1 == w:
                    print("0\n")
it do not want print q[w]

Comment: q[w] is an illegal statement becaue q is an integer object. You first need to convert it into string to perform the indexing operation use this statement int(str(q)[w])